# Does this statement make sense, as someone who cannot read my mind?

Tags: meaning

"The change into new social contexts and phases of life is a complex process involving a negotiated equilibrium between sacrifices and opportunity. "

This is in response to an essay question

"The experience of change demands compromise between sacrifice and opportunity"

Comment: What are you asking?  (You're right, we cannot read your mind!)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Haha, does the statement I wrote make sense?

""The change into new social contexts and phases of life is a complex process involving a negotiated equilibrium between sacrifices and opportunity. " in response to the essay question provided?

Comment: The percentage of the words in your sentence that are abstract or metaphorical is too high for your readers to make sense of what you wrote.

Comment: The essay "question" is not a question, but a statement. And your "response" is little more than a restatement of the "question".   It's as if the assignment were "please recast this statement with more words."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock It's not my complete response, really. It is the beginning and supposed to be a restatement (this is how my essay begins). As long as it makes sense I am happy with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a generalized request for copyediting/proofreading help with a sentence. If the poster had asked something specific about a point of grammar or usage in the sentence, the question might have passed muster.